# Excel VBA - Connection string to Teradata not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a tool in Excel VBA that is supposed to connect to Teradata and get the purchase order details. It works properly on my laptop, but when I share the tool with others, the connection string below does not connect. while troubleshooting on their laptop, I saw that the user is able to connect to Teradata using SQL assistant. But the Excel VBA string does not connect at all.

below function runs and CN.state always returns '0'

```
Function Connect(Server As String, Database As String) As Boolean

    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim UserId As String
    Dim Password As String

    Call CenterLoginWindow

    'Input UserID and Password here
    UserId = Login.Username
    Password = Login.Password

    With CN
        ' Create connecting string
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Server & ";" & _
           "Database=" & Database & ";" & _
           "Persist Security Info=True;Session Mode=ANSI;" & _
           "Uid=" & UserId & ";" & _
           "Pwd=" & Password & ""
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        ' Open connection
        .Open
    End With
    ' Check connection state
    If CN.State = 0 Then
        Connect = False
    Else
        Connect = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Using TD Auth Mech, I use the connection string: `SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;DBCName=<SERVERIP>;Database=<DEFAULTDATABASE>;CharSet=ASCII;Uid=<USERNAME>;Pwd=<PASSWORD>` which looks very different from yours. I've never had any problem with this one. I'm not sure how you get away without specifying the driver in your string.

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions for you:
1. Are the users in some other domain that would necessitate their using a different connection string?
2. What error are you getting when they try to connect?  I don't see any error handling in the above code.
3. I see you have a very short timeout specified.  Have you tried lengthening it?

Comment: Could you stick this in a comment to OP's question as it's not an answer.

Comment: I would like to, but I'm not a level 50 yet.